# wso2 cloning from two different api

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am trying to clone 2 different api to combine their response but i am always getting a null pointer error. at first i am just trying to clone these 2 api.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/movieapi" name="movieapi" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="GET" uri-template="/movie/{imdbId}">
        <inSequence>
            <property expression="get-property('uri.var.imdbId')" name="uri.var.imdbId" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <clone>
                <target>
                    <endpoint>
                        <address trace="disable" uri="https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/{uri.var.imdbId}?api_key=code&amp;append_to_response=casts,images"/>
                    </endpoint>
                </target>
                <target>
                    <endpoint>
                        <address trace="disable" uri="http://www.omdbapi.com/?type=movie&amp;i={uri.var.imdbId}"/>
                    </endpoint>
                </target>
            </clone>
        </inSequence>
    </resource>
</api>
```

Here is my error from wso2esb version 5 beta

```
[2016-07-15 13:57:34,106] ERROR - PassThroughHttpSender Failed to submit the response
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.SourceResponseFactory.create(SourceResponseFactory.java:67)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.submitResponse(PassThroughHttpSender.java:463)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.invoke(PassThroughHttpSender.java:264)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendBack(Axis2Sender.java:212)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.Resource.process(Resource.java:348)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:336)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.apiProcess(RESTRequestHandler.java:120)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:100)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:55)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:304)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:541)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:179)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:252)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2016-07-15 13:57:34,121] ERROR - Axis2Sender Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*,Cache-Control:public, max-age=28800,Content-Type:application/json;charset=utf-8,ETag:"37a6259cc0c1dae299a7866489dff0bd",Status:404 Not Found,X-Memc:MISS,X-Memc-Age:0,X-Memc-Expires:28800,X-Memc-Key:d0c5ca8e07e81f5246e96c9e4bd54753,X-RateLimit-Limit:40,X-RateLimit-Remaining:39,X-RateLimit-Reset:1468562263,<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soapenv:Body/></soapenv:Envelope> Unexpected error sending message back
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Failed to submit the response
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.handleException(PassThroughHttpSender.java:613)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.invoke(PassThroughHttpSender.java:266)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendBack(Axis2Sender.java:212)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.Resource.process(Resource.java:348)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:336)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.apiProcess(RESTRequestHandler.java:120)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:100)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:55)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:304)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:541)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:179)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:252)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.SourceResponseFactory.create(SourceResponseFactory.java:67)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.submitResponse(PassThroughHttpSender.java:463)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.invoke(PassThroughHttpSender.java:264)
    ... 16 more
[2016-07-15 13:57:34,124]  INFO - LogMediator To: http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous, WSAction: , SOAPAction: , MessageID: urn:uuid:f814f333-463b-4f51-89f1-2c361d7c55ae, Direction: response, MESSAGE = Executing default 'fault' sequence, ERROR_CODE = 0, ERROR_MESSAGE = Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*,Cache-Control:public, max-age=28800,Content-Type:application/json;charset=utf-8,ETag:"37a6259cc0c1dae299a7866489dff0bd",Status:404 Not Found,X-Memc:MISS,X-Memc-Age:0,X-Memc-Expires:28800,X-Memc-Key:d0c5ca8e07e81f5246e96c9e4bd54753,X-RateLimit-Limit:40,X-RateLimit-Remaining:39,X-RateLimit-Reset:1468562263,<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soapenv:Body/></soapenv:Envelope> Unexpected error sending message back, Payload: {"status_code":34,"status_message":"The resource you requested could not be found."}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether your property retrieve value from the property. For that use log mediator as follows;

```
<log level="full">
<property expression="get-property('uri.var.imdbId')" name="uri.var.imdbId" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
</log>
```

Then the issue is retrieving part.

Issue is about submitting response. According to your configuration, you didn't add aggregate mediator to gather responses [1]. Please add and test it.

I add sample scenario here. You just have to start 2 instances of SimpleStockQuote service [2] and publish messages to proxy via SOAPUI.

```
<proxy name="ScatterGatherProxy" startOnLoad="true" trace="disable" transports="https http">
<description/>
<target>
    <inSequence>
        <clone>
            <target>
                <sequence>
                    <send>
                        <endpoint name="vendorA">
                            <address uri="http://localhost:9001/services/SimpleStockQuoteService/"/>
                        </endpoint>
                    </send>
                </sequence>
            </target>
            <target>
                <sequence>
                    <send>
                        <endpoint name="vendorB">
                            <address uri="http://localhost:9002/services/SimpleStockQuoteService/"/>
                        </endpoint>
                    </send>
                </sequence>
            </target>
        </clone>
    </inSequence>
    <outSequence>
        <log level="full"/>
        <aggregate>
            <completeCondition>
                <messageCount min="2"/>
            </completeCondition>
            <onComplete expression="//m0:return"
                xmlns:m0="http://services.samples" xmlns:m1="http://services.samples/xsd">
                <enrich>
                    <source clone="true" xpath="//m0:return[not(preceding-sibling::m0:return/m1:last &lt;= m1:last) and not(following-sibling::m0:return/m1:last &lt; m1:last)]"/>
                    <target type="body"/>
                </enrich>
                <send/>
            </onComplete>
        </aggregate>
    </outSequence>
</target>
```

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Aggregate+Mediator

[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Setting+Up+the+ESB+Samples#Starting%20the%20Axis2%20server

Comment: it does retrieve the value from the property.
`[2016-07-15 14:17:40,029]  INFO - LogMediator To: /movieapi/movie/tt0918940, MessageID: urn:uuid:be033ca6-0430-4284-9942-569d65fe8f87, Direction: request, uri.var.imdbId = tt0918940, Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soapenv:Body/></soapenv:Envelope>`

Comment: Error is about failed to submit the response. You didn't put any mediator to get the response. You should add aggregate mediator to get responses from endpoints

Comment: Changed my answer with references.

Comment: I'm new to wso2 and i'm still trying to figure this out.
http://pastebin.com/A6riiYuv and here's my new xml http://pastebin.com/kK3M0cxa

Comment: Can I get the response you get from your backend ? New error indicating that your response hasn't anything called "body/*" According to respond you must indicate the aggregating point. I will point out a sample scenario through my answer. That will help you.

Comment: I can't seem to find any example that uses json as their response.
response from omdbapi: http://pastebin.com/e4w0uhXy and from themoviedbapi: http://pastebin.com/qVXnJrXg so what i wanted to do is merge these two response
Thanks!

Comment: Refer this blog for aggregating two json formats: http://www.vitharana.org/2015/03/aggregate-two-rest-responses.html

Comment: I was only able to get the omdbapi response. here's my config http://pastebin.com/2C6u8v9G and here's the log from terminal http://pastebin.com/QVB8v0d7 and here's the response http://pastebin.com/wCXWdc9m